# jenkins multibranch jenkinsfile SVN checkout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile located in [my svn branch]\build folder, and it checks out code to the slave node and builds.

My multi branch project finds the branch correctly, but it checks out the entire svn branch on the master just to read the jenkinsfile instead of checking out just the jenkinsfile itself of just [my svn branch]\build folder.

This is a major problem because of storage and performance, are there any solutions for that?

Answer (score 3):

In your multibranch pipeline config in 'include' field type: branches/*/build  (i assume that you have all svn branches in folder 'branches', and url to your build folder is something like: svn_url/branches/my_new_branch/build)
Then it will scan only build folder in each branch.

Warning - after changing that config property your multibranch pipeline will only diacover 'build', if you want to index other build folders, you can list them in that property, i.e.:
Include: trunk/build, trunk/other_build, branches/*/build, branches/*/other_build
But more clean approach is to get only one build per multibranch pipeline